# Shortcode attributes causes 500 error after updating the page

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, 500-internal-error

I have created a shortcode that allows me to pass an attribute like so `[product_swatch swatchtype="swatch"]`. It works fine on the front end, but every time I update the page it leads to a 500 error. If no attributes are passed or the attribute returns nothing, updating the page is as per normal.

I'm quite stumped because WP_DEBUG doesn't bring up anything either.

Here's the relevant function:

```
function product_swatch_shortcode($atts)
{
    $swatch_shortcode_atts = extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'swatchtype' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $swatch_args = array (
        'post_type'      => 'swatch',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'swatch-type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $swatchtype,
            ),
        ),
    );

    // The Query
    $swatch_query = new WP_Query( $swatch_args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $swatch_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $swatch_query->have_posts() ) {

            $swatch_query->the_post();

            $swatch_name = get_the_title();
            $swatch_image_small = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( '', 'medium' );
            $swatch_image_big = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( '', 'full' );
            $interactive_designer_link = types_render_field( 'swatch-interactive-designer-link', array('output' => 'raw') );
            $preview_image = types_render_field( 'swatch-preview-image', array('output' => 'raw') );
            $swatch_id = strtolower( preg_replace('/\s+/', '', get_the_title()) );

            $output  = '<a href="javascript:;" data-fancybox data-src="#' . $swatch_id . '" class="swatch"><img src="' . $swatch_image_small . '">' . $swatch_name . '</a>';
            $output .= '<div id="' . $swatch_id . '" class="lightbox swatch-details">';
            $output .= '<div class="swatch-col1"><h5>' . $swatch_name . '</h5><img src="' . $swatch_image_big . '">';
            $output .= '<a href="' . $interactive_designer_link . '" class="btn" style="margin:30px 0;">VIEW PRODUCT IN SIMULATION</a></div>';
            $output .= '<div class="swatch-col2"><img src="' . $preview_image . '"></div></div>';

            echo $output;

        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue to be the `types_render_field()` function (I am using the Toolset plugin). Switched to using `get_post_meta()` instead and it works fine.